# How to click on pseudo:before and pseudo:after in selenium

Tags: java, html, css, selenium

I tried with action class, but could not click on radio button.
please suggest any other option.

My Code:

```
List<WebElement> myList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='editEmployeePopup']//div//tbody//tr[2]//td[1]"));
        Actions build = new Actions(driver);
        build.moveToElement(myList.get(0)).moveByOffset(-40, -3).click().build().perform();
```

HTML Code:

```
<tr class="emp-bg" style="display: table-row;">
<td class="work-link work-detail" style="">
    <div class="">
        <p style="">
            <input type="radio" id="edit_em0" class="workLocPlot_edit" name="work_location_edit" wlpk_id="1736" data_wl_id="Kaghaznagar" lat="26.38" wl-name="Adilabad" lon="72.5" />
            <label for="edit_em0">::before
            ::after</label>
        </p>
    </div>
</td>
<td class=" work-link work-detail" style="">Kaghaznagar</td>
<td class=" work-link work-detail">Adilabad</td>
```

Screenshot :

[image]